# How to do a toggle button?

Tags: html, dom

I'm trying to do some kind of button that follow for when you scroll then and stick to the left side.

I was able to do it but was under other stuff and wasn't clickable.

I would like something like they have on this website: http://semantic-ui.com/modules/sidebar.html

On the left when you click on it the menu open. I already have that working. I'm just looking for the button how to make it like that. Because mine doesn't go on top and not clickable but follow me...

Comment: tried something anything yet mate?

Comment: I did. I have a toggle buttom it's working. I just need a button that goes on top of follow me when I scroll down.

I don't want the code for the menu. Just like the css code for that  and a design like that. The rest is working fine

Comment: try to use [position:fixed](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) and z-index in CSS or try it using javascript and position the element new when scrolled

Comment: That is working and how to do make a button like on the website? Like the right side with circle corner (Only on right side).